# Customising UIBarButton Item Image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

So I am trying to customize a bar button item for this slideoutmenu I am creating. I want it to be a particular image. However I am having trouble doing this. Whenever I try to change the image programatically by saying

```
menuButton.image = UIImage(named: "myImage.png")
```

It appears to be all stretched. Whenever I tell it to be set to an image using the attribute inspector, it will do the same thing, and I am unable to resize it in the Main Storyboard and interface builder. I imagine the fix to be simple, but I am unable to figure it out. Is there possibly a way to customize the size of the navigation controller to give it more room? Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I misunderstood the question originally. It sounds like what you are asking is how you resize the image, because it's all stretched out. It might take a little adjusting, but you can set the image insets on the `UIBarButtonItem` programmatically:

```
menuButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)
```

This is just telling the button to draw the image inset 5pts from the top, 5pts from the left, 5pts from the bottom, and 5pts from the right. You can tweak those values until it looks how you wish.